API Integration: How to get complete order information from Shopware
I am developing an API integration with Shopware.
Unfortunately, I don't have access to full control over the Shopware web site.
The whole project is being developed by GetPrintBox (PBX).
Some information: they made a controller for printing photos and photo albums based on Shopware. Of course, I don't have access to most of the functions of the admin panel, including the code.
The task: I need to send orders to CRM.
I have already developed the basic code, it looks something like this:
$date = new \DateTimeImmutable();
$now = $date->format($this->gpbFormatDateTime);
$datetime_start_get_new = date($this->gpbFormatDateTime, (int)$datetime_start_get_new);

if ($datetime_start_get_new == FALSE) {
    //get all orders (first request)
    $orderDateTime = [
        'type' => 'range',
        'field' => 'orderDateTime',
        'parameters' => [
            'gte' => '2022-01-01', // => (from)
        ]
    ];
} else {
    $orderDateTime = [
        //if data has been created (in configs file) - get last orders
        "type" => "range",
        "field" => "orderDateTime",
        "parameters" => [
            "gte" => $datetime_start_get_new, // => (from)
            "lte" => $now // <= (to)
        ]
    ];
}


try {
    $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', $this->baseUri . '/api/order', [ //ok
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],

        'query' => [
            'sort' => [
                [
                    'field' => 'orderNumber',
                    'order' => 'asc'
                ],
            ],
            "filter" => [
                $orderDateTime,
            ],
            'associations' => [
                'lineItems' => [
                    'associations' => [
                        'product' => [
                            'limit' => 1000, //all
                            'filter' => [
                                "type" => "equals",
                                "field" => "active",
                                "value" => true
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                "deliveries" => [],
                'billingAddress' => [
                    'limit' => 1,
                    'associations' => [
                        'country' => [
                            'limit' => 1
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]


        ]


    ]);
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    $response = $e->getResponse();
}

$status_code = $response->getStatusCode();

$body = $response->getBody();
$contents = $body->getContents();

$response = json_decode($contents);
if ($status_code == 200) {
    $message = 'Action "getOrders NO Update". NO ERROR, Order received';
    Logger::log($message);
    return $response;
} else {
    $message = 'Action "getOrders". Error: ' . $status_code . '. Info: ' . $response->errors[0]->title;
    Logger::log($message);
    return FALSE;
}

I get this:

Example order:
[0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [extensions] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [foreignKeys] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [extensions] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [apiAlias] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [_uniqueIdentifier] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                    [versionId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                    [translated] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [createdAt] => 2024-05-26T11:21:55.334+00:00
                    [updatedAt] => 2024-05-26T12:17:50.335+00:00
                    [orderNumber] => 10669
                    [currencyId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                    [currencyFactor] => 1
                    [salesChannelId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                    [billingAddressId] => fda035734dc64f16a4ae3ca827ed6ec8
                    [orderDateTime] => 2024-05-26T11:21:54.624+00:00
                    [orderDate] => 2024-05-26T00:00:00.000+00:00
                    [price] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [extensions] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [netPrice] => 730
                            [totalPrice] => 730
                            [calculatedTaxes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [taxRules] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [positionPrice] => 730
                            [taxStatus] => tax-free
                            [rawTotal] => 730
                            [apiAlias] => cart_price
                        )

                    [amountTotal] => 730
                    [amountNet] => 730
                    [positionPrice] => 730
                    [taxStatus] => tax-free
                    [shippingCosts] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [extensions] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [unitPrice] => 0
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [totalPrice] => 0
                            [calculatedTaxes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [taxRules] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [referencePrice] => 
                            [listPrice] => 
                            [regulationPrice] => 
                            [apiAlias] => calculated_price
                        )

                    [shippingTotal] => 0
                    [orderCustomer] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [extensions] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [foreignKeys] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [extensions] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [apiAlias] => 
                                        )

                                    [internal_mapping_storage] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [extensions] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [apiAlias] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [_uniqueIdentifier] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [versionId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [translated] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [createdAt] => 2024-05-26T11:21:55.330+00:00
                            [updatedAt] => 
                            [email] => Denis@denis.com
                            [orderId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [salutationId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [firstName] => Denis
                            [lastName] => Denis
                            [title] => 
                            [vatIds] => 
                            [company] => 
                            [customerNumber] => 10736
                            [customerId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [customer] => 
                            [salutation] => 
                            [order] => 
                            [remoteAddress] => 91.196.55.0
                            [id] => 4008bc562a9047fd98c5707c8b8c1566
                            [customFields] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [pbx_pbx2_model_name] => Customer
                                    [pbx_pbx2_customer_id] => 76249
                                )

                            [orderVersionId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [apiAlias] => order_customer
                        )

                    [currency] => 
                    [languageId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                    [language] => 
                    [salesChannel] => 
                    [addresses] => 
                    [billingAddress] => 
                    [deliveries] => 
                    [lineItems] => 
                    [transactions] => 
                    [deepLinkCode] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq-q
                    [autoIncrement] => 806
                    [stateMachineState] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [extensions] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [foreignKeys] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [extensions] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [apiAlias] => 
                                        )

                                    [internal_mapping_storage] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [extensions] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [apiAlias] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [_uniqueIdentifier] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [versionId] => 
                            [translated] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => In Progress
                                    [customFields] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [createdAt] => 2021-01-29T18:24:22.731+00:00
                            [updatedAt] => 
                            [name] => In Progress
                            [technicalName] => in_progress
                            [stateMachineId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [stateMachine] => 
                            [fromStateMachineTransitions] => 
                            [toStateMachineTransitions] => 
                            [translations] => 
                            [orders] => 
                            [orderTransactionCaptures] => 
                            [orderTransactionCaptureRefunds] => 
                            [orderTransactions] => 
                            [orderDeliveries] => 
                            [fromStateMachineHistoryEntries] => 
                            [toStateMachineHistoryEntries] => 
                            [id] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [customFields] => 
                            [apiAlias] => state_machine_state
                        )

                    [stateId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                    [documents] => 
                    [tags] => 
                    [affiliateCode] => 
                    [campaignCode] => 
                    [customerComment] => 
                    [ruleIds] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [1] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [2] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [3] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [4] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                            [5] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                        )

                    [createdById] => 
                    [createdBy] => 
                    [updatedById] => 
                    [updatedBy] => 
                    [itemRounding] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [extensions] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [decimals] => 2
                            [interval] => 0.01
                            [roundForNet] => 1
                            [apiAlias] => shopware_core_framework_data_abstraction_layer_pricing_cash_rounding_config
                        )

                    [totalRounding] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [extensions] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [decimals] => 2
                            [interval] => 0.01
                            [roundForNet] => 1
                            [apiAlias] => shopware_core_framework_data_abstraction_layer_pricing_cash_rounding_config
                        )

                    [id] => 007e0f8c20244319a65c524d6a2173ee
                    [customFields] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [pbx_pbx2_order_id] => 185
                            [pbx_pbx2_model_name] => Order
                            [pbx_pbx2_order_is_testing] => 
                        )

                    [billingAddressVersionId] => qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                    [apiAlias] => order
                )

(I replaced some data with the “q” symbol)
Problem: I do not receive complete information about the order. For example, I do not receive information about deliveries and payments.
In the settings, I saw that I don't have the “Administrator” access right.


I need help. Thank you!

UPDATED:
Hi. I've figured out my problem.
If anyone is interested:
Administrator rights have nothing to do with it.
You just need to write the request correctly.)
For example, for transactions:
"transactions" => [
                            'limit' => 1,
                            "associations" => [
                                "paymentMethod" => [
                                    'limit' => 1,
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],

For example, for deliveries:
"deliveries" => [
                            'limit' => 1,
                            "associations" => [
                                "shippingMethod" => [
                                    'limit' => 1,
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],

All this must be specified in the request.
The logic of the system is that each object needs to be asked, let's say, to make a request, for receive it.

If you have any additional questions, please contact me and I will try to help.
